# Do i need to enqueue empty style.css in a custom Wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I know this question sounds simple but i'm unable to figure out, if it's a hard requirement to `wp_enqueue_style()` the theme's `style.css` or if it can be left out.

According to documentation it is required that this file exists for Wordpress to recognize the theme, but it's not made clear if it also has to be enqueued.

In my case, I'm using sass to compile my styles into a main.css file, which in turn leaves the style.css empty and technically useless other than being a additional network request made.

Is there any penalty or disadvantage for not enqueueing the style.css in my custom theme?

Comment: You can make a blank style.css file in the theme directory, with only the theme initialization comment. I think it's enough for the theme.

Comment: But do i also need to enqueue it in functions.php or is this step unnecessary?

Comment: While I do not believe it is necessary, it is good practice if you keep a bank file.

Comment: It is necessary , a theme wont work without a style.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`style.css` is necessary for theming - telling WordPress which theme to activate, that being said you do not have to load it on the front end.

It is good practice to enqueue your custom css files so you dont have any conflicts with scripts and styles loaded from plugins.